# SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Execution Plan not getting missing index suggestions

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, collation

I have several SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 that have server collation `Latin1_General_BIN`.  These instances will not give me the missing index suggestion with performing an execution plan.  I have other instances that do work.  I can use the following TSQL code to test my results
By performing a execution plan on the select statement I get the missing index suggestion with my instances that do not have collation `Latin1_General_BIN`.  The instances that have collation `Latin1_General_BIN` do not get the suggestion.  PeopleSoft requires me to have this collation on my instances.  This worked months ago, but now does not work.  I have reset the SQL Servers and re-installed MSSMS on my desktop.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.smorg(blamp INT);
GO

INSERT dbo.smorg(blamp) SELECT n FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c1.object_id)
  FROM sys.all_objects AS c1, sys.all_objects AS c2

) AS x(n);
GO

SELECT blamp FROM dbo.smorg WHERE blamp BETWEEN 100 AND 105;
```

Comment: Different collations may result in different execution plans. If this collation is required, there isn't much you can do but you could [specify a collation for the query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) if it's necessary to receive the index suggestions.

Comment: Why have you come to the conclusion that the collation has anything to do with this query or the missing index suggestions not being shown? Sounds unlikely on the face of it. Have you come across something that would support this?

Comment: Are you having performance problems or are you simply wondering why the suggestion is missing? Do you have any indexes involved in the query you are running?  One thing about collations to note is that *_BIN sorts on the bit patterns, while collations like *_CI_AI create an index that combines characters such as A,a,À,à  or ß,ss as the 'same' character for searching purposes.  (Oversimplified explanation, of course.)